# How to get string from List<String> by JBOSS Drools

Tags: drools

i have a `List<String>`  i want something as below

```
Rule "List_iterate"
 when
   $str : String from List<String>
 then 
    // some action of $str
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Lists as facts is not a good practice. It is always convenient to use a wrapper class. But if you want to go with the List you could write something like this:

```
Rule "List_iterate"
when
  $list : List()   //Be careful, this will match against all the Lists you have in your session.
  $str : String() from $list
then 
  // some action of $str
end
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks ... i got this , well in my case it was not working as before inserting this list to global i was inserting another fact in Ksession. i guess global must be inserted first in session than only that works . with that analysis its working for me.